# facebook API problem with IIS7

Tags: php, facebook, curl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

I'm having problems with the facebook example code.

`Fatal error: Uncaught CurlException: 60: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed thrown in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\src\facebook.php on line 616`

I found a solution that I don't know what to do with [here](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=225380). I'm running IIS7 and trying to test this on localhost. The solution specified that I should add

`$opts[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = [PATH]/apache/conf/ssl.crt/ca-bundle.crt"; //Or your path to "ca-bundle.crt"`

to the code. I found the array where this info should go but I have absolutely no idea where the certificates are stored. I searched my machine for my self-signed cert ("myown") but couldn't find it. I googled for the location of cert files on IIS7 but realized I'd be better of here since maybe I don't even need to specify SSL certs.

Any suggestions? What I want to do is just to be able to run the code, I don't have any requirements of SSL right now.

Answer (score 0):

i think that the certificate is being returned but can not be validated, within C# you can usually do something like so:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate{
    return true;
};
```

so this is a callback that's executed before the certificate is validate and acts as a user validation method.

WARNING: this will validate all certificates regardless

never used IIS but im sure it would be something along these lines.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My problem concerns php so I'll have to research a bit how I could do this.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit in how I would use this solution, if I were to use .NET instead of PHP?